# Getting undefined on module exports

Tags: node.js, import, export

I'm getting a undefined when exporting a object with multiple functions as fields.

I'm exporting them as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  getArticleById: getArticleByIdFromModel
}
```

When I'm trying to importing

```
const { getArticleById } = require('../article/Article.selectors.js');
// or 
const selectors = require('../article/Article.selectors.js')
```

I'm getting both undefined, on getArticleById and selectors. Is my exporting syntax wrong? or something else? I'm using node 9.11.2

Comment: How is declared `getArticleByIdFromModel`?

Comment: Is a binded function:
`const getArticleByIdFromModel = getArticleById.bind(null, model);`
where getArticleById is:
`const getArticleById = ({ articles }, id) => articles.find(article => article.id === id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a cyclic dependency. I was importing `A` to `B` and `B` to `A`